# How do I change a static variables value in PHP?

Tags: php, static-variables

This is a simplified version of what I want to accomplish:

In my script I want a variable that changes true and false everytime the script is executed.

```
<?php
    static $bool = true;

    // Print differente messages depending on $bool
    if( $bool == true )
        echo "It's true!";
    else
        echo "It's false!";

    // Change $bools value
    if( $bool == true )
        $bool = false
    else
        $bool = true;
?>
```

But obviously what I'm doing is wrong. The variable `$bool` is constantly `true` and I haven't fully grasped the concept of static variables I presume. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PHP is not able to keep variable values between requests. This means that each time your script is called, the `$bool`-variable will be set to true. If you want to keep the value between requests you have to use [`sessions`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or, if you want the variable shared between sessions, some caching mechanism like [`APC`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [`Memcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).

Also, `static` is used in PHP to declare a variable shared on the class level. It is thus used in classes, and accessed like `self::$variableName;` or `Foo::$variableName`

You can read more about [static properties here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). From the docs:

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

Also, note that the word `static` has been overloaded since PHP 5.3, and can also be used to denote *[Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)*, by use of `static::`

Comment: Hmm.. So if I moved the static variable to a class, would I then be able to switch it's value back and forth between the executions of my main script?

Comment: No. Static can be used to declare class variables or within function to declare a variable which persists over function calls, but not over executions of the script.

Answer (score 2):

A static value will not persist over executions.
Every time the script is executed $bool is initialized.
I think you should persist this value in a file to keep it simple.

Comment: I thought that was the point with static variables, that they DO persist over executions. I'd prefer not to keep it in a separate file or is that the only solution?

Comment: You can use Memcache, APC, Redis, a file... whatever you want. But you have to store the current value of the variable somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to better understand the point of a static variable. The storage for the variable is allocated (and deallocated) on the call stack, so from a software engineering point of view, its value cannot be changed in run time.

There are better solutions as suggested above for this.

Comment: Actually, static variables in PHP are not static at all.. their values can be changed during execution. It's just a shared variable of a class.

Comment: This enables code like `class Lookup { protected static $_cache = array(); public function expensiveLookup ($x) { if(!isset(self::$_cache[$x]) {self::$_cache[$x] = $this->_lookup($x);} return self::$_cache[$x]; }}`

Answer (score -1):

It's an easy thing to use static keyword in php. Here I've used a static variable and a static method. Just try this out.

```
<?php
   class Test{
        protected static $myVar;
        public static function printHello(){         
            self::$myVar = 'Hello'; //This will assign the value to the static variable $myVar
            echo self::$myVar;  //This prints the value of static variable $myVar
        }
    }
    Test::printHello();
?>
```