# How to set and access static variable outside of namespace in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had one php class in namespace App\Http\Lib as GISApplication which contains static data members. I want to set & access values of that static data members from different classes outside of namespace. How Can I set & access that values.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Lib; 

class GISApplication
{
      public static $LOGINUSER_TYPE;
      public static $USERMODULE;

      // More Static Data Members

}
```

Suppose I want to set values of these members from LoginController class in App\Http\Controllers namespace & access that values from different classes in App\Http\Operations namespace.

I set values from LoginController class in App\Http\Controllers namespace AS

```
GISApplication::$LOGINUSER_TYPE = $auth->type;
GISApplication::$USERMODULE = $auth->module;
```

When I access values from FrontOperation class in App\Http\Operations AS

```
GISApplication::$LOGINUSER_TYPE
```

I will getting blank value.

Please suggest.

Comment: This should be fine from syntactical point of view. Check whether $auth->type and $auth->module really returns non-blank values in point of assignment and also check whether you are accessing static variable after assignment.

Comment: @IvoHrádek : I already checked values within $auth->type & $auth->module, both contains non-blank string values. Also I am sure that I am accessing variables after assignment. 

Please suggest any change that i can't figure out.

Comment: I am tried with getter & setter methods also, but no luck. 

     public static function setLoginUserType($UserType) {
         self::$LOGINUSER_TYPE = $UserType; 
     }
 
  public static function getLoginUserType() {
         return self::$LOGINUSER_TYPE; // "QWERTY";
     }

Any suggestion.

Sorry for not able to format code in comment well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables in PHP does not retain value after page refresh/postback. So every time I try to access value, I am getting blank value. I got this idea from below link

[How do I change a static variables value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497161/how-do-i-change-a-static-variables-value-in-php)

To solve the problem I used Session variable in LoginController as

```
$_SESSION['LOGINUSERTYPE']  = $auth->type;
$_SESSION['USERMODULE'] = $auth->module;
```

To access in different controllers, simply use

```
$user= $_SESSION['LOGINUSERTYPE'];
```

If any other suitable way, please suggest.